# Battery monitor on fluxbox

Tags: battery, fluxbox

I was using fluxbox on my notebook, but it missed battery indicator.Is there any battery monitor on fluxbox?

[solved]

install `wmbattery` then add it to startup script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using conky which is a great lightweight system monitor that can not only monitor your battery state but many, many other functions of your computer.

Comment: I know about those conky, but I need an indicator that look like widget

Answer (score 2):

In Manjaro Fluxbox there is a simple battery indicator applet called `cbatticon`.

I prefer `mate-power-manager`, which is more complete and looks better.

Answer (score 1):

I dislike the look of slids and don't want to install something as heavy as `xfce4-power-manager` so I am using [xbattbar](http://iplab.aist-nara.ac.jp/member/suguru/xbattbar.html). It's in the repos and adds a green bar on the top/bottom according to your battery status.

Answer (score 0):

xfce4-power-manager works fine for me

Comment: How did I not answer the question? I recommended that the asker use xfce4-power-manager in fluxbox.

Comment: Well in that case i will delete my comment , but i guess you really needed to clarify if OP tried it or not , then it could have been answer no doubt. You may need to expand your answer how does it works or provide the needed Indicator if provided somehow, thanks.